# How can I wrap my python module in a tar?

Tags: python-2.7

I created a simple `__main__.py`:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print 'the rain in Spain falls mainly on the plane'
```

I can create a zip with `__main__.py` using the command `zip -r test.zip __main__.py`

Now I can call test.zip:

```
$ python test.zip
the rain in spain falls mainly on the plane
```

When I create a tar with `__main__.py` using the command `tar -cf test.tar __main__.py`

When I call it, I get the following.

```
$python test.tar
File "test.tar", line 1
  __main__.py    print 'the rain in spain falls mainly on the plane'
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What do I have to do for python to recognize it like the zip?

Comment: In Python 3, `print` is a function, not a keyword

Comment: Thanks, I know, but I'm using python 2.7

Comment: Well, then, that's an oddly Python 3-ish error to get.

Comment: I don't believe `python` has created an import module for tar files yet. Try reading on import modules for zip and create an import module for tar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can use `tar` as Python. I have never heard of being able to run compressed Python files, but never mind.

Here is your tarred file:

```
00000000: 7465 7374 5f74 6172 2e70 7900 0000 0000  test_tar.py.....
00000010: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000020: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000030: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000040: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000050: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000060: 0000 0000 3030 3030 3634 3400 3030 3031  ....0000644.0001
00000070: 3735 3000 3030 3031 3735 3000 3030 3030  750.0001750.0000
00000080: 3030 3030 3132 3400 3132 3733 3730 3137  0000124.12737017
00000090: 3634 3600 3031 3133 3637 0020 3000 0000  646.011367. 0...
000000a0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000000b0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000000c0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000000d0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000000e0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000000f0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000100: 0075 7374 6172 2020 0063 6174 0000 0000  .ustar  .cat....
00000110: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000120: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0063 6174 0000 0000  .........cat....
00000130: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000140: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000150: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000160: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000170: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000180: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000190: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000001a0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000001b0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000001c0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000001d0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000001e0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000001f0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000200: 6966 205f 5f6e 616d 655f 5f20 3d3d 2027  if __name__ == '
00000210: 5f5f 6d61 696e 5f5f 273a 0a20 2020 2070  __main__':.    p
00000220: 7269 6e74 2027 7468 6520 7261 696e 2069  rint 'the rain i
00000230: 6e20 5370 6169 6e20 6661 6c6c 7320 6d61  n Spain falls ma
00000240: 696e 6c79 206f 6e20 7468 6520 706c 616e  inly on the plan
00000250: 6527 0a0a 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  e'..............
00000260: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000270: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000280: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000290: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000002a0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000002b0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000002c0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000002d0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000002e0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000002f0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000300: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000310: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
```

It ends in about 9K of null bytes, so this is just the first 50 lines of `xxd`, but it's not valid syntax.

It finds the filename, then lots of weird unprintable characters, then `print`. `test_tar.py` looks like a module name (and statement returning a value) so it's fine. But

```
test_tar.py print 'blah'
```

is simply not valid Python.

Comment: Just an FYI. https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0273/ Added the ability to import from a zip. And a xxd of my test.zip looks even worse than an xxd of my tar. Could I tar it in a way that will make it look similar to python?

Comment: @Bamcclur As alvitis said in the comments, I don't think there is a module for that yet, so not yet, no.